# How to create a invisible column in mysql from laravel migration?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Since MySQL 8.0.23 it supports an [invisible column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-columns.html).
But how do I create an invisible column from the Laravel migration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create it by adding `invisible()`

It has been added in [this pr](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40002) and it has been released in Laravel [v8.76.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.76.0).

Answer (score 0):

Make the column "invisible" to SELECT * queries (MySQL).

```
  $table->string('foo')->invisible();
```